Trouble adding support for mulitiple locals NixOS
Running latest stable NixOS
I am trying to add support for my 2nd language using the i18n.supportedLocales option in my configuration.nix file.
  i18n.supportedLocales = [
    "ko_KR.UTF-8/UTF-8"
  ];

The /UTF-8 Seems to be required
For reference here are the rest of my locale settings:
  # Set your time zone.
  time.timeZone = "Australia/Melbourne";

  # Select internationalisation properties.
  i18n.defaultLocale = "en_AU.UTF-8";

  i18n.extraLocaleSettings = {
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_AU.UTF-8";
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_AU.UTF-8";
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_AU.UTF-8";
    LC_MONETARY = "en_AU.UTF-8";
    LC_NAME = "en_AU.UTF-8";
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_AU.UTF-8";
    LC_PAPER = "en_AU.UTF-8";
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_AU.UTF-8";
    LC_TIME = "en_AU.UTF-8";
  };

Here is the error it throws when rebuilding with this command: sudo nixos-rebuild switch --flake .:
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_AU.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
setting up /etc...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_AU.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_AU.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").

Hope someone can decode this for me
I have spent a long time googling and scrolling through forums and can't find anything useful on the matter. I have also experimented with it myself using the MyNixOS website for information on packages and their options.

I've been confused by this before too, but the answer is pretty simple.
i18n.supportedLocales defines the complete list of supported locales for your system; anything that you do not list will not be supported. That is why the errors you see refer to "en_AU.UTF-8": that locale no longer exists in your system configuration. What you probably want is this:
  i18n.supportedLocales = [
    "en_AU.UTF-8"
    "ko_KR.UTF-8/UTF-8"
  ];

Personally, I like to set i18n.supportedLocales = [ "all" ]; it avoids having to think too hard about this issue at the cost of some disk space.
